# What is the position of Meta.SO on reviewing answers?

Tags: discussion, review

I have started reviewing posts on SO casually and there is one point where I am not sure what the community wants in regards to reviewing answers. I have seen people "correcting" answers by changing parts of the code in the answer. Except for the obvious typos and mistakes, is it ok to accept the modification if it does make it better ?

I'm not sure that it would be the best way to go because a reviewer might mistakenly accept a correction that makes the answer worse hence defacing the post in some way. At the same time it does make for better answers in the case that the editor did improve the answer.

Thoughts ?

(For the moment I skip those reviews so that I do not incorrectly accept/reject edits).

Edit: Here is an example of a minor edit on an answer with 235 upvotes. Should this kind of edit be a comment ? If I find one of the more important edits I will add it to this list.

[How to remove border (outline) around text/input boxes? (Chrome)](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/2151280)

Comment: For me I skip any where it obviously changes the technical aspect and I'm not familiar enough with the subject to judge the difference.  If I am familiar enough, then I approve/reject based on those merits.  I would tend towards 'reject' though (or skip), unless I were sure.

Comment: For the given link, I'd have used Too minor instead of incorrect edit.

Comment: Well, it's clearly not too minor; it changes code.  It wasn't a unanimous approval; I personally would have simply left a comment.

Comment: For that one I'd agree with too minor, and also say that it's a matter of style, not a matter of actual correctness.  outline:none works fine, after all, and it's not like any real page follows w3c 100% perfectly (you can't, oftentimes, as the perfect usage isn't supported by the browsers!)...

Comment: @RobertHarvey I'd say it's too minor because of the style issue - it's not changing the functionality of the answer, just making it slightly more stylistically valid.  Equivalent in my mind to changing someone's c++ code that uses { } on the same line as code to be on separate lines.

Comment: Changing code changes the meaning of the post, in most cases (unless its formatting changes only).  That trumps too minor.

Comment: The specific example here, though, _is_ effectively formatting - changing 'outline:none' to 'outline:0' has no effect on any browser.  It's the CSS equivalent of adding or removing an oxford comma.

Comment: @Joe No, it isn't formatting. A formatting edit to code is changing indentation or spacing, or putting it inside a `<code>` span, i.e., how it's presented on SO. An edit to code *that just happens to generate formatting rules* is not the same thing, and neither is an edit which changes the style of the code as written. That's altering the content of the information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suggested edits to code, other than for formatting and presentation, should be rejected, using the "invalid edit" category. As you note, these edits can change the code, and possibly make it worse. Even just correcting a typo in the code or an obvious performance improvement should be rejected. The correct action to take is comment on the post, not edit the code.

Why? Because it changes the meaning of the post in a substantive way. SO is about coding. Changing another's code changes what they're saying, and it might make an error in a question disappear, or turn a wrong answer in to a correct one. One of the editing rules is always respect the intent of the original author, and such changes fail to do so.

Comment: I think that it's okay to make edits that change the code if it's a typo or something to that effect - I've certainly made mistakes and not been online to correct them before.  I don't think it's okay to make an edit that changes how the code was _intended_ to be written, however.

Comment: @Joe Correcting those minor mistakes isn't appropriate. It could fix something that doesn't compile, for example. Additionally, it might hide a solution to an obvious pitfall from future visitors to the site, and that's in direct opposition to the goals of SE.

Comment: Why not?  If my posted answer is "for (i=1; i=100; i++) { stuff }", why wouldn't I be happy if you edited my answer to be i<=100?

Comment: @Joe Because that changes the number of times the loop executes. It introduces a substantial change to the code. Did you mean for it to be `i<=100` to begin with? Maybe, but any editor has no way of knowing that, and so an edit to that effect makes a prima facie change to the code's intent.

Comment: Obvious mistakes are pretty clear, I'd think.  If it's not obvious, then I agree with you; but for typos, I don't see what the issue is.  Who would ever want to write the original 'loop' statement?  (Assuming it was for a regular loop, and not something where i=100 makes sense.)

Comment: Conversely we edit questions to high hell in the hopes of making them answerable.

Comment: @Joe I'd be weary of changing `=` to `<=` in your example too. However, if I mistype e.g. `tempalte<typename T> ...` in an answer, correcting that to `template` would in my opinion be a perfectly valid and legitimate edit.